# Multiple Row to Single Row in a single Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

**I need an Sql to get data in a single row from multiple Row.**
FYI, i am using Microsoft sql server.

**Example:**

```
StudentId|StudentName|CourseName
1        |X          |CSE-1201
3        |Y          |CSE-1201
1        |X          |EEE-1201
```

**Output Be Like:**

```
StudentId|StudentName|CourseName
1        |X          |CSE-1201, EEE-1201
3        |Y          |CSE-1201
```

I tried with group by. But its getting aggregate functions related error. I can understand why its getting error. But i cannot solve this problem. I got different types solution which related to joining table. Like T-SQL,Stuff, Joining etc.

But i cannot understand, what they actually do. I want to understand with my given scenario.

Comment: MySQL or (MS)sql-server

Comment: its (MS)sql-server. I cannot add here this tag

Answer (score 1):

You cant string aggregation.

In MySQL, use `group_concat()`:

```
select
    studentId,
    studentName, 
    group_concat(courseName order by courseName separator ', ') courseNames
from mytable
group by studentId, studentName
```

In SQL Server 2017 or higher, use `string_agg()`:

```
select
    studentId,
    studentName, 
    string_agg(courseName, ', ') within group(order by courseName) courseNames
from mytable
group by studentId, studentName
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
But I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012. It returns "there is no built in functions named group_concat"

Answer (score 1):

Since you tag SQL Server 2008

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    VALUES
    (1, 'X', 'CSE-1201'),
    (3, 'Y', 'CSE-1201'),
    (1, 'X', 'EEE-1201')
  ) T(StudentId, StudentName, CourseName)
)
SELECT StudentId, 
       StudentName,
       STUFF(
             (
               SELECT ',' + CourseName 
               FROM CTE T 
               WHERE StudentId = TT.StudentId
               FOR XML PATH('')
             )
            , 1, 1,'') Result
FROM CTE TT
GROUP BY StudentId, StudentName;
```

But remember, you should upgrade right now. [End support SQL Server 2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/support/sql/end-support-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

For MySql try,

```
    SELECT StudentId, StudentName, dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(CourseName) 
          FROM TableName 
          GROUP BY StudentId, StudentName
```

For SQL Server try,

```
select StudentId, StudentName, stuff((select '; ' + a.CourseName
          from TableName a
           Group By StudentId, StudentName
          for xml path ('')
         ), 1, 2, '')  as CourseNames
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
i tried with your 2nd code. But its getting error 'Invalid column name 'StudentId'.' I have field named 'StudentId'.But it showing this type error

Comment: May be its because we have an alias defined in the above query so
either remove the alias or write column names as a.StudentId , a.StudentName etc.
(also you have to replace "TableName" with the name of the table.)